# Android Activity Recognition - Reconnecting following Disconnection

Tags: android, google-play-services, activity-recognition

With Google Play Services' Activity Recognition, they recommend that if the service disconnects (which it might) then we should remove the client:

http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html

> In some cases, Location Services may disconnect from the activity
>   recognition client before you call disconnect(). To handle this
>   situation, implement onDisconnected(). In this method, set the request
>   flag to indicate that a request is not in progress, and delete the
>   client

That's fine, but it gives no instructions for how to reconnect [safely]. I'm running this from a foreground service which needs to maintain activity recognition at all times, so following disconnection:

```
@Override
    public void onDisconnected() {

        mRecognitionEnabled = false;
        mRequestInProgress = false;
        mRecognitionClient = null;

        //Re-initialise Activity Recognition if service is still running
        if (sServiceRunning) {          
            triggerActivityRecognition();
        }
    }
```

I reinstantiate the client and reconnect:

```
private void triggerActivityRecognition() {

    if (!mRequestInProgress ) {

        mRequestInProgress = true;          
        mRecognitionClient = new ActivityRecognitionClient(this, this, this);
        mRecognitionClient.connect();
    }    
}
```

But according to some of the bug reports I'm getting, there's an exception occurring as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.google.android.gms.internal.bh.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.k.f(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.k$e.onServiceConnected(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.l.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.k.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionClient.connect(Unknown Source)
at com.myapp.MyService.triggerActivityRecognition(MyService.java:316)
at com.myapp.MyService.onDisconnected(MyService.java:407)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.k.A(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.k$e.onServiceDisconnected(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.internal.l$a$a.onServiceDisconnected(Unknown Source)
```

The disconnection occurs rarely but results in the same stack trace every time.

So if this is being caused by Google Play Services, is there anything I can do to prevent it or is it a bug I need to log with Android?

Comment: OK, so I think the issue was that I was trying to reconnect from within onDisconnect()'s scope, which was causing the problem. 

Also didn't realise that the client did not need to remain connected for updates to continue to be received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what works for me:

Don't attempt the reconnect with the onDisconnect(), instead do nothing in the onDisconnect()

```
public void onDisconnected() {
 //do nothing here  
}
```

Simply use the client as before, but check if is connected

```
if (!mRecognitionClient.isConnected()) {
    // Client is disconnected, reconnect now
    mRecognitionClient.connect();
}
```

The PlayServices seems to reconnect very nicely.

Comment: I agree. I think I had misunderstood the purpose of the recognition client; it does not need to remain connected for recognition updates to be sent through. Thanks.